# Ecommerce transactions often have incorrect quantity

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

**Update:** I now have a transaction with a quantity of 13! I.e. the same `transactionId` but many transactions. I have tested my `transactionId` generator and it seems ok, so I'm really not sure what's happening

**Question:**

Trying to use Google Tag Manager to do some ecommmerce tracking

I think I have everything set up correctly, but I'm getting some quantity values of 0 for my transactions, some of 1 (which is correct), and some even of 13

It's set to have a static value of 1 quantity, here is my dataLayer code:

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
'transactionId': '504210532.1395946032.72', // <? echo $id.".".time().".".rand(1,100); ?>
'transactionTotal': 1.00,
'transactionProducts': [{
'sku': 'prod1',
'name': 'Product',
'price': 1.00,
'quantity': 1
}],

**OTHER DATALAYER PROPERTIES**

}];
</script>
```

The only dynamic thing is the `transactionId`, the rest is all static

The tag fires only on a certain page; firing doesn't seem to be the issue, it's just not always getting the right quantity in there for some unknown reason

Comment: Just a quick initial question: Have you included the above dataLayer before the GTM-snippet? 

I can't really see anything other wrong with your code and you say it fires fine, so I assume something else must be wrong. How long did you wait before you noticed transactional data? Sometimes I have seen it correct itself over its nightly calculations.

Comment: Hi, yes dataLayer is above the GTM snippet; this hasn't corrected itself after a few days

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (yet), but do you have a way to prevent duplicate firing of the ecommerce snippet code? Google Tag Manager's ecommerce snippet will fire each time the receipt page is loaded. My guess is that's why you're seeing some strange numbers - because if someone refreshes, hits the back button, etc. it'll cause duplicate fires. I've seen  weird things happen without this so I ALWAYS make sure I have it implemented.

Can't remember exactly where I found this solution originally, so I apologize, I can't cite my source (will update if I find it). **But here is a solution that will prevent the ecommerce snippet from firing twice within Google Tag Manager.**

Add this as a CustomHTML snippet that fires on the checkout complete page.

```
 <script> 
 // CustomHTML only trigger on /checkout/sale-complete.html and gtm.dom ready 
 function createCookie(name,value,days) { 
 if (days) { // If not provided, it will be a session cookie. 
 var date = new Date(); 
 date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000)); 
 var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); 
 } 
 else var expires = ""; 
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; 
 } 

 function readCookie(name) { 
 var nameEQ = name + "="; 
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); 
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) { 
 var c = ca[i]; 
 while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length); 
 if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length); 
 } 
 return null; 
 } 

 if (!readCookie('cookie_hasPurchaseRecordedAlready')) { 
 createCookie('cookie_hasPurchaseRecordedAlready', 'true', 1); 
 } 
 </script>
```

The script creates a new cookie.

Next make a new 1st Party Cookie Macro, name it Purchase Cookie and give it the value of 'cookie_hasPurchaseRecordedAlready'

On your ecommerce UA code, ADD a blocking rule - {{Purchase Cookie]] equals true.